# Javascript render code take a lot of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have problem with my js/jq code. I download data via $.get in json and trying to use loop to display data. My code works but some times my json data have 300-400 records and redner takes a lot of time.
How I can optymalized this ?

My code:

```
var selectData = '';
var selectHtml = '';
var krzeselkaArray = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    DownloadData(<?= h($q->id_kontrahent) ?>);
});

function turnOffLoader(){
    $('.loader').remove();
}

function DownloadData(oid){
    $.get("<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'json','action'=>'KontrahenciKonfiguruj'],true)?>/"+oid, function(r){


        selectData = r.select;

        selectHtml = $('<select>');
        for(var x = 0, len = Object.keys(r.select).length; x < len ; x++){
            var obj = r.select[x];
            selectHtml.append($('<option>').val(obj.Tkaniny.id_tkaniny).text(obj.Tkaniny.nazwa));
        }


        for(var x = 0, len = Object.keys(r.konfiguracja.data).length; x < len; x++){
            var obj = r.konfiguracja.data[x];
            var obj_y = $('.konfiguratorHeaderTable').find('td[data-krzeselkoid="'+obj.id_krzesla+'"]').index();

            var konf_cache = $('.zaawansowana_edycja').find('tbody').find('tr.konfiguratorAttr[key="'+obj.TKA1.id_tkaniny+'|'+obj.TKA2.id_tkaniny+'"]');

            if(konf_cache.length == 0){
                var newHtml = $('<tr>');
                newHtml.addClass('konfiguratorAttr').attr('key',obj.TKA1.id_tkaniny+'|'+obj.TKA2.id_tkaniny);

                for(var t1=0;t1 < $('.konfiguratorHeaderTable').find('.obr').find('td').length; t1++){
                    newHtml.append('<td>');
                }

                $('.zaawansowana_edycja').find('tbody').append(newHtml);
            }

            konf_cache.find('td:first').html('<div class="col-sm-12"><select>'+selectHtml.html()+'</select></div><div class="col-sm-12"><select>'+selectHtml.html()+'</select></div>');

            var h2 = $('<div>');
            h2.addClass('col-sm-12');
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));
            konf_cache.find('td').eq(obj_y).append(h2.html());




        }




        if(r){
            turnOffLoader();
        }

    },'json')
}
```

In addition, my code generates tables which in each td contains 10 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use native browser tools combined with batch rendering. So at the beginning instanciate a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

```
var element  = document.getElementById('ul'); // assuming ul exists
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var browsers = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Opera', 
   'Safari', 'Internet Explorer'];

browsers.forEach(function(browser) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = browser;
    fragment.appendChild(li);
});

element.appendChild(fragment);
```

And the when you create a new tag append it to the fragment. Now it wont be rendered just yet. keep doing appending till you got all you need and then append the fragment to where ever you new tags should be. Now the browser renders all in one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize many of your code :

```
h2.append($('<input>').attr('type','text'));

build this before the for loop :
var input_html='';
for(var i=0;i<your_number_of_input;i++)
    input_html+='<input type="text">';
```

Or build it with php.
At the end don't append jquery objet but directly your constructed HTML

```
 konf_cache.find('td').eq(obj_y).append(HTML_VAR_HERE);
```

And cache your jquery selector when possible (and use id, instead of class if you can).

Answer (score 1):

First of all dzień dobry,
I think the easier would be to perform the loop logic inside an anonymous function so it won't be blocking the thread.

```
var tbody = $('.zaawansowana_edycja').find('tbody');
for (var x = 0, len = Object.keys(r.konfiguracja.data).length; x < len; x++) {
    (function(idx) {
        var obj = r.konfiguracja.data[idx];
        var obj_y = $('.konfiguratorHeaderTable').find('td[data-krzeselkoid="' + obj.id_krzesla + '"]').index();
        var konf_cache = tbody.find('tr.konfiguratorAttr[key="' + obj.TKA1.id_tkaniny + '|' + obj.TKA2.id_tkaniny + '"]');

    if (!konf_cache.length) {
        var newHtml = $('<tr>');
        newHtml.addClass('konfiguratorAttr').attr('key', obj.TKA1.id_tkaniny + '|' + obj.TKA2.id_tkaniny);

        for (var t1 = 0; t1 < $('.konfiguratorHeaderTable').find('.obr').find('td').length; t1++) {
            newHtml.append('<td>');
        }

        tbody.append(newHtml);
    }

    konf_cache.find('td:first').html('<div class="col-sm-12"><select>' + selectHtml.html() + '</select></div><div class="col-sm-12"><select>' + selectHtml.html() + '</select></div>');

    var h2 = $('<div>');
    h2.addClass('col-sm-12');
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    h2.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text'));
    konf_cache.find('td').eq(obj_y).append(h2.html());

})(x);
}
```